# How to change the default recording device with code?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to write a little code that switches the Windows default recording device between *Stereo Mix* and *Microphone* with press of a button.

I'm familiar with a lot of languages but I never had any experience with Windows calls. I'd be happy if you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found an easy way to do it with batch files.

Using [NIRCMD utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) creating a batch file like this does what is needed. The argument 1 makes the device default, 2 makes it the default communications device.

```
    C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "Stereo Mix" 1
    C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "Stereo Mix" 2
```

Turns out I need to disable the other device. Making it the default is not enough. I'm still looking for answers.